# Delete lines in XML where a certain column contains duplicates

Tags: xml, duplicates, notepad++

I do not use XML often but I need to adjust some data. 
I posted a line below from notepad++. I need to delete entire lines where the LoanID is a duplicate. The files contain around 200.000 lines where 200 LoanID's are duplicate.

Because the entire line does not need to be a duplicate, but only 1 "column" I can not use the TextFX plugin.
For example, the BorrowerID may contain duplicates. Only LoanID is not allowed to contain duplicates.

line 1:

```
<ns1:Loan>ns1:Identifiers:LoanID>876298<LoanID>  <ns1:IsRegulatedLoan>ND,6</ns1:IsRegulatedLoan><ns1:Originator>TestBank</ns1:Originator><ns1:ServicerID>Testbank NV</ns1:ServicerID><ns1:BorrowerID>26547</ns1:BorrowerID><ns1:PropertyID>364239</ns1:PropertyID>
```

line2:

```
ns1:Loan ns1:Identifiers>:LoanID>819305:LoanID>
ns1:IsRegulatedLoan>ND,6/:IsRegulatedLoanns1:Originator>TestBank/ns1:Originator>ns1:ServicerID>Testbank NV</ns1:ServicerID>ns1:BorrowerID>195797:BorrowerID>
```

Comment: The XML youhave is not valid e.g. in line 2 missing < Also note that xml elements cam be spread over multiple lines (in fact the firat thing I would do on viewing is reformat so it is readable)

Answer (score 1):

Manipulating XML at the level of "lines" is not a good idea, because line endings have no particular significance and could easily change.

For this kind of operation most people would use XSLT. There's a learning curve to XSLT, but if you're going to be using XML then it's a vital part of your toolkit so it's well worth mastering it. Typical code (in XSLT 2.0) would look like this:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="ns1:Loan" group-by="LoanId">
  <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]"/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

which, given a set of duplicates, would drop all but the first.